# Why do I get a "IndexError: list index out of range" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a bubble sort in python, but I keep getting the error code: "IndexError: list index out of range". I am not sure where I am going wrong, as I don't know where my code exceeds its bounds:

```
def swaps():
    while dataset[i] > dataset[i+1]:
        temp = dataset[i]
        dataset[i] = dataset[i+1]
        dataset[i+1] = temp
        print (dataset)

dataset = ["6", "3", "5", "2", "4", "1"]
newset = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]

for i in range(0,6):
    newset[i] = swaps()
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! x

Comment: `range(0, 6)` = `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. When it gets to `5`. then `5 + 1 = 6`. and you don't have an item at `dataset[6]`

Comment: -Robert Seaman Thank you so much! x

Comment: @RobertSeaman you should make your comment an answer. Also, it's not great practice to use a global variable (`i` in this case)--especially one that's only implied. I'd suggest adding a parameter to the `swaps` function and passing `i` to it as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

`range(0, 6)` = `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. When it gets to `5`. then `5 + 1 = 6`. and you don't have an item at `dataset[6]`.

And as Zach King has pointed out - it's not good practice to use global variables in this case, passing objects through as arguments to a function would be a lot nicer.